# Parse javamail attach

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, multipart

im having a problem to get the "text/calendar" part of an email.

```
 Multipart mp = (Multipart) message.getContent();
 String s = mp.getBodyPart(1).getContent().toString();
```

This code is returning `"com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream@44b07df8"`

I read that I have to implement the read() method so I change my code:

```
 Multipart mp = (Multipart) message.getContent();

  BASE64DecoderStream base = (BASE64DecoderStream)mp.getBodyPart(1).getContent();
  base.read();
```

But this is printing in console the following string :

```
"QkVHSU46VkNBTEVOREFSDQpNRVRIT0Q6UkVRVUVTVA0KUFJPRElEOk1pY3Jvc29mdCBFeGNoYW5n
ZSBTZXJ2ZXIgMjAxMA0KVkVSU0lPTjoyLjANCkJFR0lOOlZUSU1FWk9ORQ0KVFpJRDpBcmdlbnRp
bmEgU3RhbmRhcmQgVGltZQ0KQkVHSU46U1RBTkRBUkQNCkRUU1RBUlQ6MTYwMTAxMDFUMDAwMDAw
DQpUWk9GRlNFVEZST006LTAzMDANClRaT0ZGU0VUVE86LTAzMDANCkVORDpTVEFOREFSRA0KQkVH
SU46REFZTElHSFQNCkRUU1RBUlQ6MTYwMTAxMDFUMDAwMDAwDQpUWk9GRlNFVEZST006LTAzMDAN
ClRaT0ZGU0VUVE86LTAzMDANCkVORDpEQVlMSUdIVA0KRU5EOlZ..."
```

Can someone help me and tell me what am i doing wrong please?

Comment: Did you change your println() to print the post-decode version of the content?  Also, you shouldn't need to refer to BASE64DecoderStream.  It's in the com.sun package, which you should try to avoid using as much as possible.  Finally, are you able to use MimeMultipart instead of Multipart?  You might have more success with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I realize that if I save as output stream in a file, i was able to read the content without any problems. Thanks a lot for the answer.